# VB6 IDE Keeps Crashing: Object Library Not Registered

Tags: vb6

Project is meant to be working, due to it running fine on my colleagues computer, but I am trying to run it from the VB6 IDE on windows 8 and when I click run application I keep seeing "Object Library Not Registered". When I run it a second time VB6 crashes.

I have looked at the event viewer and identified that the last loaded module was:
`LoadedModule[71]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\Wizards\RESEDIT.DLL`

Also, below is my problem signiture:

```
Problem signature:
P1: vb6.exe
P2: 6.0.81.76
P3: 3592011f
P4: VBA6.dll
P5: 6.0.0.8169
P6: 358b0c74
P7: c0000005
P8: 00171891
P9: 
P10:
```

---

Update - I was playing around with access rights, after switching it off now I have issue with below:
`LoadedModule[70]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Designer\MSADDNDR.DLL`

---

Update 2 - When i run VB6 and then load project into it I get following issue:
`LoadedModule[113]=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\ink\tiptsf.dll`

---

Update 3 - I am doing steps from "Update 2" but now it's throwing
`LoadedModule[112]=C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LINKINFO.dll`

Comment: Should the `VBA` tag be in there?

Comment: Can you successfully build a new project that includes a resource file?

Comment: I can create .exe file but I can't run the exe file.

Comment: I have to change some strings in VB6. At the moment it's not worth migratig to vb.net

Comment: Fair enough. If all else fails, you could try a Windows XP virtual machine.

Answer (score -1):

I think there might be a need to re-register the dll and ocx files (use the **regsvr32** command), as well as the tlb files (use either **regtlib**, **regtlibv12** or **regasm** command). If all libraries registered successfully, you may also need to change the **Compatibility mode** of your exe and set it to Windows XP (Service Pack 3).